# What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following piece of code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199040/scala-xml-building-adding-children-to-existing-nodes):

```
def addChild(n: Node, newChild: Node) = n match {
  case Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, child @ _*) => Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, child ++ newChild : _*)
  case _ => error("Can only add children to elements!")
}
```

Everything in it is pretty clear, except this piece: `child ++ newChild : _*`

What does it do?

I understand there is `Seq[Node]` concatenated with another `Node`, and then? What does `: _*` do?

Comment: Thank you so much for adding (colon underscore star) to the title!

Answer (score 175, accepted):

It "splats"<sup>1</sup> the sequence.

Look at the constructor signature

```
new Elem(prefix: String, label: String, attributes: MetaData, scope: NamespaceBinding,
         child: Node*)
```

which is called as

```
new Elem(prefix, label, attributes, scope,
         child1, child2, ... childN)
```

but here there is only a sequence, not `child1`, `child2`, etc. so this allows the result sequence to be used as the input to the constructor.

---

<sup>1</sup> This doesn't have a cutesy-name in the SLS, but here are the details. The important thing to get is that it changes how Scala binds the arguments to the method with repeated parameters (as denoted with `Node*` above).

The **`_*` type annotation** is covered in "4.6.2 Repeated Parameters" of the SLS.

> > The last value parameter of a parameter section may be sufﬁxed by “*”, e.g. (..., x:T *). The type of such a repeated parameter inside the method is then
> > the sequence type scala.Seq[T]. Methods with repeated parameters T * take
> > a variable number of arguments of type T . That is, if a method m with type
> > (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps : S*)U is applied to arguments (e1, . . . , ek) where k >= n, then
> > m is taken in that application to have type (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps : S, . . . , ps0S)U,
> > with k ¡ n occurrences of type S where any parameter names beyond ps are
> > fresh. **The only exception to this rule is if the last argument is marked to be
> > a sequence argument via a _* type annotation. If m above is applied to arguments (e1, . . . , en,e0 : _*), then the type of m in that application is taken to be
> > (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps :scala.Seq[S])**

Comment: We like to call it the "Smooch operator", even though it's not actually an operator :)

Comment: In Python this is called unpacking

Comment: Is there a limit to how long the sequence can be, such as there is with Java varargs?

Comment: @qwwqwwq No, no limit.  Unless, maybe there is a limit to the total number of parameters a method can take.  In that case, it would have that same limit.

Answer (score 109):

- `child ++ newChild` - sequence
- `:` - type ascription, a hint that helps compiler to understand, what type does that expression have
- `_*` - placeholder accepting any value + vararg operator

`child ++ newChild : _*` expands `Seq[Node]` to `Node*` (tells the compiler that we're rather working with a varargs, than a sequence). Particularly useful for the methods that can accept only varargs.

Comment: Could you write more about "type ascription"? What is it and how does it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascription-in-scala

Comment: Great answer. So by writing `a: _*`, you are telling the compiler to treat `a` as an instance of `_*`, which in this case just `Node*`

Answer (score 39):

All the above answer looks great, but just need a sample to explain this .
Here it is :

```
val x : Seq[Seq[Int]] = Seq(Seq(1),Seq(2))

def f(arg: Seq[Any]*) : Int = {
 arg.length
}
f(x) //1 as x is taken as single arg
f(x:_*)  // 2 as x is "unpacked" as a Seq[Any]*
```

So now we know what `:_*` do is to tell compiler : please unpack this argument and bind those elements to the vararg parameter in function call rather than take the x as a single argument .

So in a nutshell, the `:_*` is to remove ambiguity when pass argument to vararg parameter.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. The other ones are great, but this one with this simple example, made my day. Hat tip to @Keith

Comment: This is also a great example for another way:  This will unpack to two items: `Seq(1)` and `Seq(2)`.  How would I unpack to `1` and `2`?  Can I do `f(x:_*:_*)`?

Answer (score 13):

For some of the lazy folks like me, it just converts collection values to varArgs!