# What does :_* do when calling a Java vararg method from Scala?

Tags: java, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)

I’m using the REPL to call a Java vararg method with a Scala Array.

I get an error if I do this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val array = Array(classOf[String], classOf[Int])
Person.getClass.getMethod("apply", array)
```

But if I do this then it works:

```
Person.getClass.getMethod("apply", array:_*)
```

My questions is what does `:_*` do? Where is it defined in the Scala API?

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly a duplicate. Note that he calls a Java method with the repeated parameter ascription, not a Scala repeated-params method.

Comment: Stack Overflow does a lousy job at searching symbols -- in fact, it completely ignores them. If you need to search for symbols in the future, use [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com/). It will search for questions on Stack Overflow but keep the symbols.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

adding `:_*` tells the compiler to treat the array as varargs.  It works the same with Scala as with Java.  If I have a method

```
def foo(args: Int*) = args.map{_ + 1}
```

I can call it as such:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4) //returns ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

but if I want to pass an actual sequence to it (as you are with `getMethod`) I would do:

```
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
foo(mylist:_*)
```