# How to pass Scala Seq to a Java varargs

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions

I have an existing Java method like this:

```
public static MyJavaClass javaFunc(String name, long... values) {
    ...
}
```

and I need to call it from Scala with this:

```
val idList: Seq[Long] = Seq(1L, 2L, 3L)

MyJavaClass.javaFunc("hello", idList)
```

but it ends up invoking the toString method on the idList parameter.  I've tried the following to no avail:

```
MyJavaClass.javaFunc("hello", idList:_*)
```

which causes compile error:

```
no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
```

How can I pass the argument?

Comment: This should normally work, what error do you get?

Comment: This sounds more like a compiler error, that confuses me a bit. Does this class have other constructors?

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. BTW which Scala version are you using?

Comment: There are lots of them that look the same but slightly different. This is actually an ElasticSearch class: FilterBuilders.TermsFilterBuilder

Comment: Using Scala 2.10 - you are right - it is a compile error. But still, how do I call it?

Comment: Just to be sure, there is TermFilterBuilder, which takes only a single long and TermsFilterBuilder, which takes the varargs. Did you check for a typo?

Comment: This was a bug in scala 2.10.0, should be fixed in 2.10.1

Comment: In case anyone is wondering what `:_*` is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051356/194894

Answer (score 3):

```
// java class
public class MyJavaClass {
    public static void javaFunc(String name, long ...values) {
        for (long i: values)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```
//scala class
object Y {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val idList: Seq[Long] = Seq(1L, 2L, 3L)
    MyJavaClass.javaFunc("hello", idList: _*)
  }
}
```

it is working like this for me

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on Scala 2.10.4 and Java 8 but it seems like a bug.

You can avoid the `: _*` by adding these Java methods:

```
public static MyJavaClass javaFuncConverter(String name, long[] values) {
     return javaFunc(name, values);
}

public static MyJavaClass javaFuncConverter(String name, long value) {
     return javaFunc(name, value);
}
```

In your Scala code you call it like this:

```
val idList: Seq[Long] = Seq(1L, 2L, 3L)

MyJavaClass.javaFuncConverter("hello", idList.toArray)
MyJavaClass.javaFuncConverter("hello", idList.head)
```

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val javaList = idList.asJava
```

Comment: You've got a java List now. So, how you going to pass it into parameter as java's varargs?