# Convert Seq or List to collection.immutable.Queue

Tags: scala, collections, queue

I wonder, if there is a standard and short way to convert **Sequence** to immutable **Queue** in Scala?

I did not find a magic method in documentation.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
def toQueue[A](s: Seq[A]): Queue[A] = s match {
  case x +: xs => x +: toQueue(xs)
  case _ => Queue.empty[A]
}
```

But is there anything more convenient?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not use `s: _*`?

```
val s = List(1, 2, 3) // or Seq(1, 2, 3), as you wish
val queue = scala.collection.immutable.Queue(s: _*)
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Can you please explain or give a link to how `s: _*` syntax works? First time I see that.

Comment: Sure, here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, via factory builders applied with [`.to(factory)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html#to[C1](factory:scala.collection.Factory[A,C1]):C1):

```
List(1, 2, 3).to(collection.immutable.Queue)
// collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3)
```

Prior to `Scala 2.13` and starting `Scala 2.10`:

```
List(1, 2, 3).to[collection.immutable.Queue]
// collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s=new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Any];
var li:List[Any]=List(1,'a',"bing",4,7,9,'j');
for(i<-0 to li.length-1)
{
    s.+=(li(i))
}
```