# Scala how to convert Map to varargs of tuples?

Tags: scala, playframework

In the context of Scala Play 2.2.x testing I have a `Map[String, String]` which I need to pass to a function that accepts `(String, String)*` i.e. a varargs of `(String, String)` tuple.

e.g.

```
val data : Map[String, String] = Map("value" -> "25", "id" -> "", "columnName" -> "trades")
route(FakeRequest(POST, "/whatever/do").withFormUrlEncodedBody(data))
```

but this gives a type mismatch because `withFormUrlEncodedBody` accepts only a `(String, String)*` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply:

```
def foo(names: (String, String)*) = names.foreach(println)
val folks = Map("john" -> "smith", "queen" -> "mary")
foo(folks.toSeq:_*)
// (john,smith)
// (queen,mary)
```

Where `_*` [is a hint to compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala).

Comment: Ugh, scala compiler fail! ... why can't there be `toVarargsSeq` method on map?

Answer (score 3):

Oh found the answer e.g.

```
route(FakeRequest(POST, "/wharever/do").withFormUrlEncodedBody(data.toList: _*))
```

or

```
route(FakeRequest(POST, "/wharever/do").withFormUrlEncodedBody(data.toSeq: _*))
```

or

```
route(FakeRequest(POST, "/wharever/do").withFormUrlEncodedBody(data.toArray: _*))
```