# How to convert from Map[String,Any] to (String, String)*

Tags: scala

A function takes an input as follow:

```
myFunction("param1" -> "value1", "param2" -> "value2")
```

Parameter type in myFunction is `(String,String)*`. Now, I want to store these parameters in a map object like this:

```
val p = Map("param1" -> "value1", "param2" -> "value2")
```

The reason is because I want to pass p around before I pass it into `myFunction` like this: `myFunction([converting p to (String,String)* here])` and I cannot change the parameter type of `myFunction`. How can I convert `p` to `(String, String)*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala how to convert Map to varargs of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012146/scala-how-to-convert-map-to-varargs-of-tuples)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the map to a `Seq` and mark it as a varargs element like this:

```
 myFunction(p.toSeq: _*)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `p.mapValues(_.toString)`

Comment: This will give a `Seq[String]`, not a varargs element.