# How to pass Scala array into Scala vararg method?

Tags: arrays, scala, variadic-functions

Consider the code below:

```
private def test(some:String*){

}

private def call () {
  val some = Array("asd", "zxc")
  test(some)
}
```

It prints `expect String, found Array[String]` Why? Are Scala varargs not arrays?

**Note**

I found several questions on Stack Overflow about Scala varargs, but all of them are about calling Java varargs methods or about converting Scala lists to arrays.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Append `:_*` to the parameter in `test` like this

```
test(some:_*)
```

And it should work as you expect.

If you wonder what that magical `:_*` does, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala).

Answer (score 50):

It is simple:

```
def test(some:String*){}

def call () {
  val some = Array("asd", "zxc")
  test(some: _*)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting Scala 2.13.0, if you use `some: _*`, you will get this **warning**:

> Passing an explicit array value to a Scala `varargs` method is
> deprecated  (since `2.13.0`) and will result in a defensive copy; Use
> the more efficient non-copying `ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray` or an explicit
> `toIndexedSeq` call

As suggested, use `scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray`:

```
unsafeWrapArray(some):_*
```

Also, another warning that you should be getting is this one

> procedure syntax is deprecated: instead, add `: Unit =` to explicitly
> declare `test`'s return type

To fix that, add `=` just before function's opening bracket:

```
def test(some:String*) = {
```