# How to pass variable arguments to the Cube function in spark sql?

Tags: cube, apache-spark-sql

How to pass variable arguments to the Cube function in spark sql and also agg function of the cube?

I have a list of columns, and I want to find the cube function on the columns and also aggerations function.

For example:

```
val columnsInsideCube = List("data", "product","country")
val aggColumns = List("revenue")
```

I want something like this:

```
dataFrame.cube(columns:String*).agg(aggcolumns:String*)
```

This is not like passing scala array to the Cube.
Cube is predefined class in the datafram.we have to send it in a proper manner.

Comment: I formatted your text and fixed your grammar, because I love you. Next time do it from yourself, thank you. And don't forget: "I" is always capital case on English!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How pass scala Array into scala vararg method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

Spark (new in version 1.4)

```
import pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube
df.cube("name", df.age).count().orderBy("name", "age").show()
```

see also [How to use "cube" only for specific fields on Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763325/how-to-use-cube-only-for-specific-fields-on-spark-dataframe)

---

or HiveSQL

```
GROUP BY a, b, c WITH CUBE
```

or which is equivalent to

```
GROUP BY a, b, c GROUPING SETS ( (a, b, c), (a, b), (b, c), (a, c), (a), (b), (c), ( ))
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Enhanced+Aggregation,+Cube,+Grouping+and+Rollup#space-menu-link-content

---

or you could use other libraries like

```
import com.activeviam.sparkube._
```