# How to transform List of tuples to multiple tuples?

Tags: scala

I want to have a method that builds up query parameters for `def withQueryString(parameters: (String, String)*): WSRequest`. In particular, I have the following method:

```
def toParams: Seq[(String, String)] = {
  val params = List(
    ("firstName" -> "john"),
    ("lastName" -> "doe"),
    ("age" -> "35"),
    ("ssnr" -> "1234")
  )
  params
}
```

The problem is that the method `withQueryString` requires `(String, String)*` instead of `Seq[(String, String)]`. How can I make this conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass scala Array into scala vararg method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-to-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the `Seq` using `:_*`:

```
val result = withQueryString(toParams: _*)
```