# Passing an "Any*" varargs argument to another function that takes "Any*"

Tags: scala

I have a function like below which is auto generated by a script.

```
def printFunc(args : Any*) : Unit = {
     funcCallHandler.call(args)
}
```

The call function in the funcCallHandler looks like this. This function takes variable arguments from other generated functions too.

```
def call(args : Any*) : Unit = {

   for (arg <- args) {
       /*Check type using a match function
        and add do the rest of the code*/
   }

}
```

When I am passing the variable arguments I got from the first function to the second mentioned one I get it as a WrappedArray. Is there a way to type match this WrappedArray or is there a better approach at doing this?

The type is not specified in the case of first function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass scala Array into scala vararg method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-to-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method)

Comment: @DavisBroda The fact that `args` is itself a varargs is a different information and might be confusing (although the solution is the same indeed).

Comment: `funcCallHandler.call(args:_*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass the arguments as varargs, you need to do

```
 def printFunc(args : Any*) : Unit = {
   funcCallHandler.call(args: _*)
}
```

Otherwise, args will be understood as a single argument of type `Seq[Any]`.