# Java Reflection in Scala, Error in Passing parameters to function

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I am using Java Reflection in Scala, However when I try to invoke the function I am getting the following Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Following function present in testClass

```scala
def test(mystr:String):String ={
  return "hi"
}
```

I am calling the above function the following way

```scala
var params = new Array[Object](1)
params(0) = "hi"

//extractOject is instance of testClass
val featuresJsonStr = extractFunction.invoke(extractOject,params)
```

I read that invoke function expects parameters of function as array of objects, I am trying to do the same thing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use varargs syntax in Scala

```scala
val featuresJsonStr = extractFunction.invoke(extractOject, params: _*) // hi
```

[How to pass Scala array into Scala vararg method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064753/how-to-pass-scala-array-into-scala-vararg-method)

Or just

```scala
val featuresJsonStr = extractFunction.invoke(extractOject, "hi") // hi
```

(Please [don't](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) use `return` keyword in Scala.)