# Scala implicit conversion to a Java array not working

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala and I've hit my first hurdle ...

java.nio.file.Paths has this method:

```
public static Path get(String first, String ... more)
```

This java code compiles (and runs):

```
String[] tokens = new String[] { "/home", "toby", "mydir" };
Path path = Paths.get(tokens[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 1, tokens.length -1));
```

However this scala code does not compile:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
...
val tokens = Array("/home", "toby", "mydir")
val path = Paths.get(tokens(0), tokens.tail)
```

The error I get is `"type mismatch; found : Array[String] required: String"`

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) does not want an array as the second parameter, `String... more` is the [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) notation.

Try:

```
val path = Paths.get(tokens.head, tokens.tail: _*)
// path: java.nio.file.Path = /home/toby/mydir
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala?lq=1) for more explanation on `_*`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. This is something specific to Scala right? I mean varargs are just syntatic sugar over arrays so in Java I can pass an array