# reason for scala apply method type error(variadic function)

Tags: scala

using ***a.tail: _**** is ok 
but not ***a.tail: A**** why?

thank your help in advance

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: A, t: List[A]) extends List[A]
trait List[+A]

object List {
  def apply[A](a: A*): List[A] = {
    if (a.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(a.head, apply(a.tail: _*))
    //else Cons(a.head, apply(a.tail: A*))
  }
}
```

Comment: See also [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, when you add a star to the type of a parameter in a method body (apply, in this case), you tell Scala to accept any number of A's. This is *not* the same as saying "take a sequence of A's"; if you wanted that, you'd write `a: Seq[A]`. As far as I understand it, using `Seq[A]` could achieve the same effect as `A*`, but you'd need some boilerplate to handle the case of the empty sequence, and on instructions to traverse the sequence. Hence, it's less convenient.

Now, why can't you use `A*`? Well, because you're not declaring a type for `a.tail`; it already has a type, and that type is `List[A]`. Rather, since you need to pass it as an argument to `apply`, which takes a variable number of arguments, `A*` (a Varargs parameter), you need to tell the Scala compiler that the sequence `a.tail` (a List sequence in this case) cannot be passed to the method as a sequence: that would be a single argument, not a variable number, and thus incorrect. Instead, the `: _*` works to *adapt* the sequence into something that can be passed as a variable number of arguments, "one at a time", in essence.

So, the `: _*` signature *alters* how an existing sequence is *handled*, but that sequence already has a type, it's just a type that is incompatible with a Varargs parameter without some sort of conversion. `: _*` provides that conversion. Note how you only needed to use it because you were going to pass `a.tail` into a method, `apply`, that accepted a variable number of arguments. If you weren't passing it to a Varargs method you wouldn't need to add `: _*`.

Comment: but my IDE intelliJ shows that 'a' is `Seq[A]` and 'a.tail' is also `Seq[A]` Not `List[A]`

Comment: and 'a' comes from type `A*`. if `A*` is equal to type `Seq[A]` then why second `apply` needs conversion `_*` not just `Seq[A]` or `A*` ... or maybe `A* ⊂ Seq[A] & A* ≠ Seq[A]`?

Comment: Seq[A] is a supertype of List. Sorry, I forgot you were using a custom List definition. [Scala Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq), and then [Linear Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable). LinearSeq is a further subtype of Seq. Look at its linear subtypes and you'll see List, Stream, and a bunch of other collections.

The idea is, the compiler will be able to detect if you are constructing something that is a linear sequence, which is what your list is, and it will treat it as such. In other words, as Seq[A].

Comment: `A*` is not equal to `Seq[A]`, that's the point. `Seq[A]` is a single argument, one input, `A*` can take 0 or more different inputs. The `Seq[A]` can be converted to `n` arguments where `n = Seq[A].length`. To tell the compiler to do this you use the `: _*` type 'operator'. Does this help? Also, check Peter Neyen's comment for further clarification.

Comment: And again, an argument is something that `apply` takes as an input. Because you've made its sole argument variadic, `apply` can take any number of INPUTS, like `apply(a, b, c, d, e, f, g...)`, where each argument input is of type `A`. When you call `apply` a second time, you are making the function recursive, because it calls itself. The argument provided to the second apply (the thing in the parenthesis), is, as you pointed out, a `Seq[A]`. The types for both `apply`'s need to be identical however, and `Seq[A] != A*`, so you 'convert it' by adding `: _*`.

Comment: Also, please be sure to accept a response as an answer if it answered your question or helped you to understand it. You have two questions currently open, but have not selected an answer in either of them. I only bring this up because you've only just started asking questions on this site, and just wanted to make sure you remember to select the best answer. It won't close the thread, so further clarification by other members will still be possible.

Comment: Thank you so much Now I got understand :) Quite clear. and... about accept; unfortunately I have point 11 which is under 15 : pt 15 is the point you can accept an answer; I'm so sorry, and when I got the point I will raise up your kind detail answer