# Transform Tuples to Array of Points

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a class `Point` with two properties `x` and `y` and k tuples:

```
val p1 = (1,2)
val p2 = (3,4)
val p3 = (33,3)
val p4 = (6,67)
.
.
val p4 = (3,8)
```

I want to write a function which I can call like:

```
val arrayOfPoints = tupleToArray(p1,p2,..,pk)
```

And it will return `Array` of `Points` with

- `x` = first value of the tuple and
- `y` = 2nd value of the tuple.

Note: the number of arguments for the function can be any integer >=1.

Comment: what type this array will have?

Answer (score 4):

- If we define `Point` as a case class, we can turn a `(Int, Int)` tuple into a `Point` using `Point.tupled`.
- We can accept a variable number of arguments using the variable arguments notation `(Int, Int)*`.

A function to turn tuples into `Points` could look like :

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

def tupleToPoints(pairs: (Int, Int)*) = 
  pairs.map(Point.tupled).toArray

scala> tupleToPoints(p1, p2, p3, p4)
res2: Array[Point] = Array(Point(1,2), Point(3,4), Point(33,3), Point(6,67))
```

If you have a group of points, you can do :

```
val points = List(p1, p2, p3, p4)
tupleToPoints(points: _*)
```

---

Some extra explanation about `Point.tupled`:

When you call `Point(1, 1)`, you actually call `Point.apply(1, 1)`. If we check the type of `Point.apply`, we can see it takes two `Ints` and returns a `Point`.

```
scala> Point.apply _
res21: (Int, Int) => Point = <function2>
```

In your case we have a tuple `(Int, Int)` which we would like to turn into a `Point`. The first idea could be pattern matching :

```
(1, 1) match { case (x, y) => Point(x, y) }

def tupleToPoints(pairs: (Int, Int)*) = 
  pairs.map { case (x, y) => Point(x, y) }.toArray
  // nicer than map(p => Point(p._1, p._2))
```

But what if we want to use the tuple directly to create a `Point` using `Point.apply`, so we don't need this step ? We can use `tupled` :

```
scala> (Point.apply _).tupled
res22: ((Int, Int)) => Point = <function1>
```

We now have a function which takes a tuple `(Int, Int)` (instead of two `Ints`) and returns a `Point`. Because `Point` is a case class, we can also use `Point.tupled` which is exactly the same function :

```
scala> Point.tupled
res23: ((Int, Int)) => Point = <function1>
```

We can pass this function in our map :

```
def tupleToPoints(pairs: (Int, Int)*) = 
  pairs.map(Point.tupled).toArray
  // analogous to map(p => Point.tupled(p))
```

Comment: What if I define p =(p1, p2, p3, p4) and want to call this as tupleToPoints(p), how should I change the definition of the function?

Comment: Would `p` be a tuple or a sequence (`List`, `Array`, ...) ?

Comment: I want to define val p=((1,2),(3,4),(33,3),(6,67)) & call the method as tupleToPoints(p) and it should return the same result.

Comment: That is not as simple as you might expect. Easier would be `val p = List((1,2),(3,4),(33,3),(6,67))` then you could do `tupleToPoints(p: _*)`.

Comment: What _ signifies? and what then would be code for tupleToPoints? I mean I want to call something like: pairs.map(p=>Point(p._1,p._2)) but I see _1 and _2 doesn't work. I don't want to call tupled.

Comment: In my previous comment, `tupleToPoints` would be the same, [more info on `_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala?lq=1). I don't know why you wouldn't want to use  `Point.tupled`, but your `map` function should work too.

Comment: I am doing : case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

def tupleToPoints(pairs: _*) =
  pairs.map(p => Point(p._1,p._2)).toArray

val p = List((1,2),(3,4),(33,3),(6,67))
println(tupleToPoints(p)) but getting error: scala:3: error: not found: type _$1
def tupleToPoints(pairs: _*) =
                         ^
one error found

Comment: You should not use a tuple (like `(p1, p2, p3)`) to represent a group of points, use a `List`, `Array`, `Vector`, ...  And you cannot use `_*` inside a function definition.

Comment: As you said I am using _* where you said, pardon me if I am mistaking .

Comment: You can use `_*` when you call `tupleToPoints`, but not in its definition.