# Scala: error on overloaded Java method

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to use the library dcm4che3 in Scala

My Scala code is

```
val item: Attributes = new Attributes
val x: Int = ints.toArray.length
val vr: VR = VR.OW
val intArray: Array[Int] = ints.toArray
item.setInt(Tag.LUTData, vr, intArray)
```

and I get an error

```
Error:(125, 10) overloaded method value setInt with alternatives:
  (x$1: String,x$2: Int,x$3: org.dcm4che3.data.VR,x$4: Int*)Object <and>
  (x$1: Int,x$2: org.dcm4che3.data.VR,x$3: Int*)Object
 cannot be applied to (Int, org.dcm4che3.data.VR, Array[Int])
    item.setInt(Tag.LUTData, vr, intArray)
```

I notice in the error it is asking for an Int*. The java signature is

```
setInt(int,org.dcm4che3.data.VR,int[])
```

I understand that Array[Int] is the scala equivalent of int[]. What is an Int*? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: it's a seq. can you try: intArray: _*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int*` is a varargs parameter, the equivalent of Java's `int...`. Just like Java, you can pass an array or an arbitrary number of arguments, but to avoid the ambiguity you get in Java when you pass `null`, there's a special syntax in Scala. Call the function as follows:-

```
item.setInt(Tag.LUTData, vr, intArray:_*)
```

In fact, you probably don't need an array at all: you can pass any sequence to a varargs function in Scala, not just an array, so if your `ints` variable is some kind of sequence, you can pass it in place of `intArray`, and remove `intArray` completely.

See also [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala), which is the reverse of your question.