# Spark Dataframes: How can I change the order of columns in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

After joining two dataframes, I find that the column order has changed what I supposed it would be.

Ex: Joining two data frames with columns `[b,c,d,e]` and `[a,b]` on `b` yields a column order of `[b,a,c,d,e]`.

How can I change the order of the columns (e.g., `[a,b,c,d,e]`)? 
I've found ways to do it in Python/R but not Scala or Java. Are there any methods that allow swapping or reordering of dataframe columns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

In Scala you can use the ["splat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala) (`:_*`) syntax to pass a variable length list of columns to the `DataFrame.select()` method.

To address your example, you can get a list of the existing columns via `DataFrame.columns`, which returns an array of strings. Then just sort that array and convert the values to columns. You can then "splat" out to the `select()` method:

```
val mySortedCols = myDF.columns.sorted.map(str => col(str))
// Array[String]=(b,a,c,d,e) => Array[Column]=(a,b,c,d,e)

val myNewDF = myDF.select(mySortedCols:_*)
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is reordering after your join:

```
case class Person(name : String, age: Int)
val persons = Seq(Person("test", 10)).toDF

persons.show
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
|test| 10|
+----+---+

persons.select("age", "name").show

+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 10|test|
+---+----+
```

Comment: Once a data frame becomes unwieldy in its number of columns and the order is more than a single swap or two, what other ways are there? My guess is something to do with `columns()`(Java API) ...