# How to convert a Stream[IO, List[A]] to Stream[IO, A]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2

I want to parse a json file which output a collection of `A`. The signature of the `Output` is `IO[List[A]]`

How can I convert this value to a `Stream`: `Stream[IO, A]` ?
I can convert to a `Stream[IO, List[A]]` but it is not what I want

`fs2.Stream.eval(input).flatMap(x => fs2.Stream.apply(x))`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
fs2.Stream.eval(output).flatMap(x => fs2.Stream.apply(x: _*))
```

[What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `Stream.emits`, which accepts a `Seq`, so `fs2.Stream.eval(output).flatMap(fs2.Stream.emits(_))`.

This is more efficient than using varargs with apply because it avoids wrapping and unwrapping the sequence structure - this can save a lot in the case of specialized primitive collections.

Edit: As of more recent fs2 versions (3.9.x as I write this) there's a convenience method for this now

```
def input: IO[List[Foo]] = ???
fs2.Stream.evalSeq(input) // Stream[IO, Foo]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting annoyed with the amount of vararg conversions I was dealing with. This is much cleaner