# How to iterate through similar registers definition in Chisel (regmap)

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I have some similar register definition, and I want to write under the regmap construct.
My code currently looks like this:

```scala
val regs = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(5)(0.U(32.W))))

regmap (
...
0x30 -> Seq(RegField(32,regs(0),RegFieldDesc("reg0",""),
0x34 -> Seq(RegField(32,regs(1),RegFieldDesc("reg1",""),
0x38 -> Seq(RegField(32,regs(2),RegFieldDesc("reg2",""),
0x3C -> Seq(RegField(32,regs(3),RegFieldDesc("reg3",""),
0x40 -> Seq(RegField(32,regs(4),RegFieldDesc("reg4",""),
...

)
```

My question, is there a way to write the above in more concise way using one of the Scala Iterators?
Another requirement I have is that I still need to be able to add register before and after this iterator (3 dots lines).

I believe ,using iterators is good against copy/paste mistakes and looks better.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pattern for this would probably be something like

```scala
val regs = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(5)(0.U(32.W))))

val tuples = regs.zipWithIndex.map { case (reg, i) =>
  (0x30 + (i * 4)) -> Seq(RegField(32,regs,RegFieldDesc(s"reg$i","")))
}
regmap(tuples :_*)
```

The only bit of magic there is the :_* which converts a sequence into a list of parameters.You don't need the multiple steps that I used either, I just wanted to make it easy to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank @Chick Markley for  your answer, I am a little bit puzzled  with the :_*  . can you elaborate on that or point me to a web resource to learn about it ?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala. Basically in converts a Seq/Collection into a form where it can fill out the parameters of a function with a varargs signature, something like f(varArgs: Int*). It's cool, but doesn't come up too often

Comment: What about the commas @Chick Markley , do I need to add them to the tuples creating loop body ?

Comment: I also get the next errors, when trying that :  "no `: _*' annotation allowed here
[error] (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
[error]            iqRegs :_*"

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet, I'm not sure what commas you are referring to, or what line is giving the annotations error