# How to pass elements of a list to concat function?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe, concatenation

I am currently using the following approach to concat the columns in a dataframe:

```
val Finalraw = raw.withColumn("primarykey", concat($"prod_id",$"frequency",$"fee_type_code"))
```

But the thing is that I do not want to hardcode the columns as the number of columns is changing everytime. I have a list that consists the column names:

```
columnNames: List[String] = List("prod_id", "frequency", "fee_type_code")
```

So, the question is how to pass the list elements to the `concat` function instead of hardcoding the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `concat` function takes multiple columns as input while you have a list of strings. You need to transform the list to fit the method input.

First, use `map` to transform the strings into column objects and then unpack the list with `:_*` to correctly pass the arguments to `concat`.

```
val Finalraw = raw.withColumn("primarykey", concat(columnNames.map(col):_*))
```

For an explaination of the `:_*` syntax, see [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

Map the list elements to List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] in a separate variable.
Check this out.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("a","x-","y-","z")).toDF("id","prod_id","frequency","fee_type_code")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, prod_id: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+-------+---------+-------------+
|id |prod_id|frequency|fee_type_code|
+---+-------+---------+-------------+
|a  |x-     |y-       |z            |
+---+-------+---------+-------------+


scala> val arr = List("prod_id", "frequency", "fee_type_code")
arr: List[String] = List(prod_id, frequency, fee_type_code)

scala> val arr_col = arr.map(col(_))
arr_col: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(prod_id, frequency, fee_type_code)

scala> df.withColumn("primarykey",concat(arr_col:_*)).show(false)
+---+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
|id |prod_id|frequency|fee_type_code|primarykey|
+---+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
|a  |x-     |y-       |z            |x-y-z     |
+---+-------+---------+-------------+----------+


scala>
```