# What does ":_*" mean in scala? (When using a List to filter a dataframe)

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, underscore.js

When seeing some co-workers' Scala-Spark code, sometimes I encounter that they use lists to filter dataframes as in this example:

```
val myList: List[String] = List("0661", "0239", "0949", "0380", "0279", "0311")

df.filter(col("col1").isin(myList:_*)
```

The code above works perfectly, this one, however, does not:

```
df.filter(col("col1").isin(myList)
```

What I don't understand is, what is that "colon underscore star" `:_*` exactly doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`:\_\*\` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does mean "pass list as a separate parameters". It works for methods, that have a vararg argument, like "any number of strings", but not a `List[String]` version.

Spark's `isin` function has signature `isin(list: Any*): Column`, `Any*` means "any number of arguments of type Any". Not very descriptive, but here you can pass either any number of strings, or any number of cols.
With `:_*` syntax, you're saying to compiler "replace my list with varargs", it's equialent to writing `.isin("0661", "0239" ...)`

Also, since Spark 2.4.0 there's function `isInCollection`, that takes `Iterable`, so you can pass `List` there directly.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

This is sometimes called [`splat`](https://alvinalexander.com/bookmarks/scala/scalas-missing-splat-operator/) operator. It is used to to adapt a sequence (Array, List, Seq, Vector, etc.) so it can be passed as an argument for a [varargs](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-varargs-syntax-function-examples/) method parameter:

```
def printAll(strings: String*):Unit = {
    strings.foreach(println)
  }

val fruits = List("apple", "banana", "cherry")
printAll(fruits:_*)
```

Comment: Do we have similar operator for Map object something similar to ** of python ?

Comment: @PriyanshuSharma what is the signature of the function which you need to pass the "splatted" map? If it is something like `myFunc(tuples: (String, String)*)` then you should be able to use `myFunc(map.toSeq: _*)`.

Answer (score 4):

If any method contains any `repeated parameter`. If you want to pass any `Iterable` in the method's  `repeated parameter`, to convert your `Iterable to repeated parameter` you will use `:_*`

```
def x(y:Int*):Seq[Int]={  // y:Int* is a repeated parameter. 
 y
}


x(List(1,2,3,4):_*)  <--- you are passing List into repeated parameter
```

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you!!!!