# Understand some Scala operators

Tags: scala

I am reading some scala code and I am having some troubles understanding one code line. The code is

```
dfAssembled.select(dfAssembled.columns.filter(FinalVarList.contains(_)).map(colName => new Column(colName)): _*)
```

I understand what the select function is doing and the map function is creating column objects, but what puzzles me are the "new", the semicolon and all symbols following

Comment: For `_*` you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62623349/2501279) question.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see your comment. Now I am good. Thank you

Comment: A semicolon is an expression separator in Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map(colName => new Column(colName))
```

`map()` takes a function as an argument. The function here accepts one parameter and returns a `Column` object allocated with the `new` operator.