# Scala (Spark) concatenate Columns in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

How does the code below concatenate multiple values in the list?

`concat(myList.map(fld => col(fld)): _*)`

Comment: What certain problem? ":_*" - converting array to varargs arguments:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#concat) the signature of the [concat](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ea907469bbf15b4b43540f6c33184cc790fadcb7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3736) function is `concat(col1, col2, ..., colN)`. Given your list contains the column names, i.e: `c1, c2 ... cN`, `map` will convert each one of these into [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) class objects. The conversion is done using the [col](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ea907469bbf15b4b43540f6c33184cc790fadcb7/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L104) function. Finally, the `_*` will unpack the (converted to Column) list items, similarly to how python's [* operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) works, assigning `concat` arguments.

Comment: Thank you , this is scala and not python. Does _* work similarly in scala?

Comment: yes exactly! And by the way [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ea907469bbf15b4b43540f6c33184cc790fadcb7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3736) you can find the code for concat