# How to pass a sequence to a function accepting multiple arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

Below are my 2 functions

```
def getProductAsDouble(nums: Double*):Double={
    var n = new BigDecimal("1.0")
    nums.foreach(num => n = n.multiply(new BigDecimal(num.toString)))
    n.setScale(2,java.math.BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()
  }

  def getProductAsString(nf:NumberFormat,nums: Double*): String ={
    nf.format(getProductAsDouble(nums)) // shows error here
  }
```

I am unable to pass `nums` from `getProductAsString` to `getProductAsDouble`. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `: _*`

e.g.

```scala
def getProductAsString(nf:NumberFormat,nums: Double*): String ={
  nf.format(getProductAsDouble(nums : _*))
}
```

There is a good explanation of `_*` type annotation here: [What does `:_*` (colon underscore star) do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala)