# Append element as child of Anti-XML element

Tags: xml, scala, anti-xml

Suppose I have an XML document stored as an Anti-XML `Elem`:

```
val root : Elem =
    <foo attr="val">
        <bar/>
    </foo>
```

. I want to append `<baz>blahblahblah</baz>` to the root element as a child, giving

```
val modified_root : Elem =
    <foo attr="val">
        <bar/>
        <baz>blahblahblah</baz>
    </foo>
```

For comparison, in Python you can just `root.append(foo)`.

I know I can append (as a sibling) to a `Group[Node]` using `:+`, but that's not what I want:

```
<foo attr="val">
    <bar/>
</foo>
<baz>blahblahblah</baz>
```

How do I append it as the last child of `<foo>`? Looking at [the documentation](http://www.danielspiewak.com/anti-xml/v0.3/doc/#com.codecommit.antixml.package) I see no obvious way.

---

Similar to [Scala XML Building: Adding children to existing Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199040/scala-xml-building-adding-children-to-existing-nodes), except this question is for Anti-XML rather than `scala.xml`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Elem` is a [case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107), so you can use `copy`:

```
import com.codecommit.antixml._

val root: Elem = <foo attr="val"><bar/></foo>.convert
val child: Elem = <baz>blahblahblah</baz>.convert

val modified: Elem = root.copy(children = root.children :+ child)
```

The `copy` method is [automatically generated for case classes](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/named_and_default_parameters_in_scala.html), and it takes named arguments that allow you to change any individual fields of the original instance.

Answer (score 3):

Although not yet relevant, but there is an `addChild/ren` method on `Elem` in `master` in the Anti-XML repo.
Its implementation currently contains a bug, but there is an outstanding pull request to fix it.
So you should probably use that in a future release.

(Would've made this a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to do so.)